# upgrade mura to latest version from 5.4

Tags: coldfusion, mura

We are on mura cms 5.4. can we upgrade to version 6. I don't see the upgrade in site settings. so i might have to do it manually. 
i have tried verifying the documentation but nothing suitably mentions of the issues or compatibility.
we have coldfusion 9, sql server 2005 and wish to go with the same environment.
Are there any issues if we migrate from 5.4 to 6 directly.or is it better if we migrate to an intermediary version first.

Answer (score 2):

ATTENTION: Always take a backup of both the database and the code before upgrading

---

> We are on mura cms 5.4. can we upgrade to version 6

Yes

> I don't see the upgrade in site settings
>   Mura has to parts to upgrade: the core and the site(s).

*Upgrade the core:*

1. connect to the administrator as a super admin
2. click on "site settings" on the top right
3. Just below the title (Site Settings) there is a button "Update Core Files to Latest Version", click this button to upgrade the core

*Upgrade a site:*

1. connect to the administrator as a super admin
2. click on "site settings" on the top right
3. click on the name of the site you want to update
4. Just below the title (Site Settings) there is a button "Update Site Files to Latest Version", click this button to upgrade the site

> i have tried verifying the documentation but nothing suitably mentions of the issues or compatibility.

Mura 6 is fully backwards compatible

> we have coldfusion 9, sql server 2005 and wish to go with the same environment

Mura still supports this setup

> Are there any issues if we migrate from 5.4 to 6 directly.or is it better if we migrate to an intermediary version first.

Upgrade directly to 6, there is no need to upgrade to an intermediary version first.